# When to use one or two commas with appositives?

Tags: commas, appositives, parenthetical-commas

I can't seem to find the answer to the above question.

I know when to use no commas (essential) and when to use two commas (non-essential), but when do you use only one comma?

It appears you use only one comma for the same reason you use no commas.

Examples:

> The popular US president Barack Obama enacted many policies.

> A natural talent, Leonard Bernstein could sightread complex piano pieces from a young age.

What's the difference?

Comment: Is "A natural talent" essential or non-essential? What about "Leonard Bernstein, a natural talent, could sightread complex piano pieces from a young age."?

Comment: It's essential.  My understanding is that you use 2 commas when the appositive is non-essential.  But, when the info is essential, you use either one or none.  My question is what is the difference?

Comment: Is it syntactically essential or semantically essential?

Comment: I use one comma **only** when the appositive phrase begins or ends the sentence (but none in the Obama sentence).  In Wikipedia I am forever correcting sentences like “Bernstein, a natural talent could…”

Comment: Your second example is fine, but note that "Leonard Bernstein" is not an appositive. "A natural talent" is called a 'predicative adjunct'. It's predicative because it relates to a predicand,, i.e. "Leonard Bernstein", and it's an adjunct because it's a supplement in clause structure.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to test whether the second noun phrase is in apposition with one immediately prior is to write the sentence out twice, each with one of the NPs, and then to ask yourself, Are the two *equivalent*? You can use "the force", your sense of the language, to decide. *When the two  are not equivalent, you don't surround the second noun phrase with commas.*

Here are some examples without any comma punctuation you can use to test your sense of equivalency.

**A natural talent Leonard Bernstein could sight-read complex piano pieces.**

> A natural talent could sight-read complex piano pieces.
>
> Leonard Bernstein could sight-read complex piano pieces.

The first is a  general statement about a natural talent. It could have been  anybody who was a natural talent, whereas the second refers to a specific person. They are not equivalent.

**The first president of the United States George Washington had wooden teeth.**

> The first president of the United States had wooden teeth.
>
> George Washington had wooden teeth.

They both refer to the same person. These are equivalent.

Let's try it without the article:

**First president of the United States George Washington had wooden teeth.**

> First president of the United States had wooden teeth.
>
> George Washington had wooden teeth.

The first is not even grammatical without the definite article.  They are not equivalent. "First president of the United States" while it is an accurate *description* of George Washington is only a description not a reference.

**Lefty hurler for the Los Angeles Dodgers Sandy Koufax pitched a perfect game in 1965.**

> Lefty hurler for the Los Angeles Dodgers pitched a perfect game in 1965.
>
> Sandy Koufax pitched a perfect game in 1965.

Does the first sentence even sound right to you? Hardly. It is not grammatical without an article.  **Lefty hurler for the Los Angeles Dodgers** without an article is a *descriptor* that might be applied to any of several  pitchers on the team; it doesn't refer to one specific individual. The two are not equivalent.

**The lead soprano for the company Jane Smith had acute laryngitis and couldn't sing.**

> The lead soprano for the company had acute laryngitis and couldn't sing.
>
> Jane Smith had acute laryngitis and couldn't sing.

The two noun phrases refer to the same individual. They are equivalent.

Comment: Yes. Importantly, the sentence "[A natural talent], Leonard Bernstein could sightread complex piano pieces from a young age" does not qualify as apposition because the bracketed supplement (an ascriptive NP) cannot be substituted for the whole construction in such a way as to yield an entailment of the original. As you say, if we drop the NP "Leonard Bernstein", what remains is not the equivalent of the original.

Comment: @TimR Great answer.  I just noticed it.  The problem is in my 1st example.  Why can't "Barack Obama" be the subject and "the US President" the appositive?  If so, it should be "The popular US President, Barack Obama…"  Using your method, Barack Obama is more important thus the subject.

Comment: @QuietInMontana: I don't have any "more important" criterion in my personal definition of apposition.  My concept of apposition is that two NPs "stand in apposition", rather than one being the semantic anchor and the other being the apposite. My criteria are 1) the two NPs must reference the same entity, where "reference" is a sematic pointing-directly-at-it-and-it-alone and 2) the two NPs must have the identical syntactic role in the clause structure of the sentence. I would accept  two such NPs in direct object position, whereas I think the definition BillJ uses would reject that.

Comment: @TimRonadifferentdevice I've been thinking about what you wrote.  (I can't believe I'm spending so much time on this, which is a testament to how screwed up English is.)  With your method, can you ever use one comma?  Can you say: "The popular US president, Barack Obama enacted many policies."?  Or "A natural talent, Leonard Bernstein could sight-read complex piano pieces."?  Sounds like you are saying nay.  But some argue it's fine.  So both "The popular US president, Barack Obama enacted many policies" and "The popular US president Barack Obama enacted many policies" are correct.

Comment: With apposition, commas correspond to the syntactic pauses which, in speech, isolate the apposite NP.  These pauses occur before and after the apposite NP.   "A natural talent, Leonard Bernstein" is not an example of apposition, as "a natural talent" is non-referential.

Answer (score 0):

When using punctuation to set off "nonessential" elements, you should always use paired marks (typically commas, dashes, or parentheses, as with this comment). However, a comma (or dash) should be omitted in certain situations. *The Oxford English Grammar* says the following about paired commas:

> Enclosing commas come in pairs. . . . However, if the enclosed unit comes at the beginning of the sentence, the first comma is omitted. . . . And if it comes at the end, the second comma is absorbed by the period. . . . The omission [of the initial comma] occurs also when the initial comma is preceded by other major marks of punctuation, such as a colon, semicolon, or dash. Similary, the absorption of the second comma is applied when other major marks of punctuation follow it. (Sidney Greenbaum, *The Oxford English Grammar*, Oxford University Press, 1996, section 11.28)

Let's consider your example sentences:

> The popular US president Barack Obama enacted many policies.

This is correct, because the appositive "Barack Obama" is essential and thus does not require paired punctuation.

> A natural talent, Leonard Bernstein could sightread complex piano pieces from a young age.

This is correct, because the nonessential appositive "a natural talent" is surrounded by paired commas, the first of which is omitted because it would have appeared at the beginning of the sentence. (Some people would not consider "a natural talent" an appositive; interpretations may vary.)

Comment: The non-essential condition was unimportant.  I was only concerned when essential appositives are involved.  But, I think you answered my question.  When the appositive (which is non-essential) is at the start of the sentence, you use only one comma.  However, why do you consider "a natural talent" as the appositive?  Why isn't "Leonard Bernstein" the appositive phrase?  Is it because "Leonard Bernstein" is the more important noun?

Comment: There is one error I can see:  ""My dog, Mr. Chewy, …" does not contain an instance of apposition; that is a vocative : the sentence is adressed to Mr Chewy. (relating to or denoting a case of nouns, pronouns, and adjectives in Latin and other languages, used in addressing or invoking a person or thing. https://www.thoughtco.com/vocative-grammar-1692598)

Comment: @QuietInMontana Yes, an appositive generally provides supplementary information about its referent. You could make "Leonard Bernstein" an appositive by surrounding it with commas: "A natural talent, Leonard Bernstein, could sightread complex piano pieces from a young age." However, the meaning would be different.

Comment: @LPH "Mr. Chewy" could be a vocative in that sentence, but that doesn't seem to make much sense. Assuming that I have only one dog, then I know of no reason why "Mr. Chewy" couldn't be a nonrestrictive appositive. That would surely be the most common interpretation. (Though perhaps I should have used "Fido" to make the intended meaning clearer?)

Comment: Further: "A natural talent" is called a 'predicative adjunct'. It's predicative because it relates to a predicand,, i.e. "Leonard Bernstein", and it's an adjunct because it's a supplement in clause structure.

Comment: @BillJ Yes, I'm aware of how you interpret such phrases. That's why I wrote the second footnote. If you want to try to convince me (yet again) that your interpretation is the only correct one, then I'm sorry to say that once more you'd be yelling into the wind.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan You might add a parenthesis then, such as "'Mr Chewy' is the dog's name".

Comment: @LPH I'm actually running out the door right now, but I'll try to think about how to make it clearer and maybe edit it later. Thanks!

Comment: Appositives are **always** post-head modifiers (or supplements). They **never** precede the noun they refer to, thus "a natural talent" cannot possibly be an appositive. Further, if you think that "Leonard Bernstein" may be an appositive, forget it. Appositives **specify**  another noun, but it can hardly be said that Leonard Bernstein is specifying "a natural talent"; it's a descriptive NP, not a specifying one. It's clear that the OP's example has nothing to do with apposition.

Comment: @BillJ The notion of adjunct, in other words, the notion of adverbial is not logical: the adverbial has to do with the verb in the clause (_ad_ + _verbum_); the adverbial impinges upon the action of the verb. There is no such association to the verb in "A natural talent, Leonard Bernstein could sightread…"; all that can be made out is a copular relation between "A natural talent" and "Leonard Bernstein" ("Leonard Bernstein is a natural talent"); CoGEL also does consider this a case of apposition, and I think their thinking is sound.

Comment: @BillJ The etymology  is not  explanatory because in fact "verbum" means "word".

Comment: If CoCEL consider "a natural talent" to be an appositive, they are wrong. Appositives are post-head modifiers (or supplements), not pre-head ones: they **always follow** the noun they refer to, but never precede it, thus ruling out "a natural talent" as an appositive. FYI, 'adjunct' includes supplements attached to a clause, which is what "a natural talent" is.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan To summarise, the sentence "[A natural talent], Leonard Bernstein could sightread complex piano pieces from a young age" does not qualify as apposition because the bracketed supplement (an ascriptive NP) cannot be substituted for the whole construction in such a way as to yield an entailment of the original. In other words, if we drop the NP "Leonard Bernstein", what remains is not the equivalent of the original.

Answer (score 0):

> [1] *The popular US president* [*Barack Obama*] *enacted many policies.*
>
> [2] *[A natural talent, [*Leonard Bernstein*] *could sightread complex piano*
> *pieces from a young age*.

Both your examples are fine and punctuated correctly, but only [1] contains apposition.

In [1] the NP, "Barrack Obama", is clearly an integrated appositive modifier of the definite NP "the popular US president": it specifies which US president is being referred to. Importantly, the appositive thus provides a formulation that can stand instead of the NP containing it, i.e. an entailment of the original, which is a fundamental requirement of an appositive NP.

But there is no apposition in [2]. "Leonard Bernstein" cannot be an appositive NP since it can hardly be seen to be specifying the indefinite NP "a natural talent". And if it is dropped, what remains is not an entailment of the original.

Note that the NP "a natural talent" cannot be an appositive, since appositive NPs follow the noun the refer to, never precede it. Syntactically, it's called a 'predicative adjunct'. It's predicative because it relates to a predicand, i.e. "Leonard Bernstein", and it's an adjunct because it's a supplement in clause structure, a loosely attached element set off by intonation and punctuation presenting supplementary information.

Comment: Why do you believe that appositives can't precede the noun?  I'm curious to know your rationale.  Also, I don't understand your description of "natural talent" as a predicative adjunct.  Predicative adjuncts relate to the predicate, not the predicand, no?  And since "a natural talent" refers to "Leonard Bernstein", it's an appositive.  No?